# Negation of -2147483648 not possible in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int num=-2147483648;
  int positivenum=-num;
  int absval=abs(num);

  std::cout<<positivenum<<"\n";
  std::cout<<absval<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Hi I am quite curious why the output of the above code is

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

Now I know that `-2147483648` is the smallest represntable number among signed ints, (assuming an `int` is 32 bits). I would have assumed that one would get garbage answers only after we went below this number. But in this case, +2147483648 IS covered by the 32 bit system of integers. So why the negative answer in both cases?

Comment: Use _int64 instead of int and try again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But in this case, +2147483648 IS covered by the 32 bit system of integers.

Not quite correct. It only goes up to +2147483647. So your assumption isn't right.

Negating `-2147483648` will indeed produce `2147483648`, but it will overflow back to `-2147483648`.

Furthermore, signed integer overflow is technically undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The value -(-2147483648) is *not* possible in 32-bit signed int. The range of signed 32-bit int is –2147483648 to 2147483647

Comment: darn I was going to answer, but +1

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh, but its not... remember 0, largest signed is actually 2147483647

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2's complement representation of signed integers isn't symmetric and the minimum 32-bit signed integer is -2147483648 while the maximum is +2147483647. That -2147483648 is its own counterpart just as 0 is (in the 2's complement representation there's only one 0, there're no distinct +0 and -0).

Here's some explanation.

A negative number -X when represented as N-bit 2's complement, is effectively represented as unsigned number that's equal to 2<sup>N</sup>-X. So, for 32-bit integers:
if X = 1, then -X = 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 = 4294967295
if X = 2147483647, then -X = 2<sup>32</sup> - 2147483647 = 2147483649
if X = 2147483648, then -X = 2<sup>32</sup> - 2147483648 = 2147483648
if X = -2147483648, then -X = 2<sup>32</sup> + 2147483648 = 2147483648 (because we only keep low 32 bits)

So, -2147483648 = +2147483648. Welcome to the world of 2's complement values.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers have all pointed out that the result is UB (Undefined Behaviour) because `2147483648` is not a valid `int32_t` value. And we all know, UB means anything can happen, including having daemons flying out of your nose. The question is, why does the `cout` behavior print out a negative value, which seems to be the worst value it could have chosen randomly ?

I'll try to justify it on a two's complement system.  Negation on a CPU is actually somewhat of a tricky operation. You can't do it in one step. One way of implementing negation, i.e. `int32_t positivenum = -num` is to do a bit inversion followed by adding 1, i.e. `int32_t positivenum = ~num + 1`, where `~` is the bitwise negation operator and the `+1` is to fix the off-by-one error. For example, negation of `0x00000000` is `0xFFFFFFFF + 1` which is `0x00000000` (after roll over which is what most CPUs do). You can verify that this works for most integers... except for 2147483648. 2147483648 is stored as 0x80000000 in two's complement.  When you invert and add one, you get

```
- (min)        = -(0x80000000)
               = ~(0x80000000) + 1
               =   0x7FFFFFFF  + 1
               =   0x80000000
               =   min
```

So magically, the unary operator `-` operating on `min` gives you back `min`!

One thing that is not obvious is that two-complement CPUs' arithmetic have no concept of positive or negative numbers! It treats all numbers as unsigned under the hood.  There is just *one* adder circuit, and *one* multiplier circuit. The adder circuit works for positive and negative numbers, and the multiplier circuit works for positive and negative number.

Example: -1 * -1

```
 = -1         * -1
 = (cast both to uint32_t)
 = 0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF
 = FFFFFFFE00000001         // if you do the result to 64 bit precision
 =       0x00000001         // after you truncate to 32 bit precision
 =                1
```

The only time you care about signed vs unsigned is for comparisons, like `<` or `>`.